# Redirect user to external URL in controller action

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I am trying to add online payment to my application and it requires me to post a form to their website like so.  It has a few required hidden inputs (I'm just showing one of them for the transaction total).

```
<form action="https://thirdpartysite.com/clientpostback" method="POST">
    ...
    <input type="hidden" name="TransTotal" id="TransTotal" value="135.00" />
    ...
</form>
```

Instead of posting to their website from the view, I want to post to a Controller in my application so I can update their application saying they agreed to the terms and conditions.

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Review(ApplicationReviewViewModel vm)
{
    if (ModelState.IsValid())
    {
        _appBusiness.Update(vm);

        // Now I need to post to the third party website and pass in the posted values
        return RedirectToAction("https://thirdpartysite.com/clientpostback");
    }
}
```

How would I redirect users to the third party site from my controller action?  Is that possible?

Comment: You can't initiate a POST request from a redirect, no.  You can do so from client-side code.  What do you have to do to the POST request that requires server-side code anyway?

Comment: I wanted to POST on the server-side to verify that the users wouldn't tamper with the hidden inputs.  If they're supposed to pay $135 I want to make sure they don't change the hidden input value to $5.

Comment: I suspect the payment provider has means of validating that with you.  You might want to check with their support, it may even be in a FAQ somewhere.  (If they don't have any means to prevent that abuse, use a different payment provider.)  If you POST from server-side code then it would be *you* who is posting to the payment provider, not the user.

Comment: Side note: what you are trying to do is likely against rules of your billing provider...

Comment: After transaction most online payment services sends you some kind acknowledgement together with amount payed. At this point just compare it with value user was supposed to pay and fail if both do not match.

Comment: Thank you, those are all good points.  I will review the payment provider documentation and compare the amount they payed with the amount they were supposed to pay.